# How to block abusive IP addresses with pf in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, pf

We can see from the nginx logs that there is an IP address doing nasty things.

How can we block it with a `pf` command and then later permanently with the `/etc/pf.log`? How can we block a `x.x.x.x/24` for that IP? It is example: 1.2.3.4

UPDATE: no, looks like OpenBSD doesn't have allow/deny file in /etc. And AFAIK the best advise for blocking abusive IP addresses are using pf.

```
# cd /etc 
# ls -la|egrep -i 'deny|allow'
# uname -a
OpenBSD foo.com 5.4 GENERIC.MP#0 amd64
#
```

Comment: Do you have a hosts.deny file in the /etc directory?

Answer (score 15):

The best way to do this is to define a table and create a rule to block the hosts, in `pf.conf`:

```
table <badhosts> persist
block on fxp0 from <badhosts> to any
```

And then dynamically add/delete IP addresses from it:

```
$ pfctl -t badhosts -T add 1.2.3.4
$ pfctl -t badhosts -T delete 1.2.3.4
```

Other 'table' commands include `flush` (remove all), `replace` and `show`. See `man pfctl` for more.

If you want a more permanent list you can keep it in one (or more) files. In `pf.conf`:

```
table <badhosts> persist file "/etc/badguys1" file "/etc/badguys2"
block on fxp0 from <badhosts> to any
```

You can also add hostnames instead of IP addresses. See the "Tables" section of `man pf.conf` and `man pfctl`.

**Note**: *The examples above assume that the internet-facing interface is `fxp0`, please change according to your setup. Also, keep in mind that the rules  in `pf.conf` are evaluated sequentially and for `block` or `pass` rules its the last matching rule that applies. With this ruleset*

```
table <badhosts> persist
block on fxp0 from <badhosts> to any
pass inet tcp from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 80
```

*and after adding 1.2.3.4 and 192.168.0.10 to the `badhosts` table*

```
$ pfctl -t badhosts -T add 1.2.3.4
$ pfctl -t badhosts -T add 192.168.0.10
```

*all traffic from 1.2.3.4 and 192.168.0.10 will be blocked but the second host **will** be able to make connections to other machines' port 80 because the `pass` rule matches and overrides the `block` rule.*

Comment: The block rule can be more easily specified as `block in from <badhosts>`.  You don't need to specify interface or the `to any` part.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear from other answers that you need to create an actual table of the badhosts you are trying to block.

This goes in the pf.conf file, for example I have two badguys files, 1&2
badguys1 is for those who come and go, and badguys2 is for permanent blacklisting.

So if you need to add an ip of someone who is a nuisance for a period of time, add them to badguys1.

Now, in your pf.conf file you have this.
In my example I use en1, because that's my WiFi interface. Set that to what ever interface your network comes in on.

```
table <badhosts> persist file "/etc/badguys1" file "/etc/badguys2"
block on en1 from <badhosts> to any
```

Now you can add temporary addresses to badguys1.  (NOT badhosts, that's a name for the tables)

```
sudo pfctl -t badguys1 -T add 185.130.5.160

1 table created.
1/1 addresses added.
```

Although it says 1 table created - it actually adds the ip, not creating a new table.
Now if you look in badguys1, you will see the new IP.

```
sudo pfctl -t badhosts -T show
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this information from the website and forgive me for my ill knowledge of `OpenBSD`, but here it goes. Take a look at this [URL](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-block-ip-address-with-pf-on-freebsd-netbsd-and-openbsd/). According to it, it states to block an IP you would:

`echo '123.123.123.123' >> /etc/pf.blocked.ip.conf`

Then you would restart the firewall:

```
pfctl -d
pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf
```

Or, to add without restarting the firewall type:

`pfctl -t blockedips -T add 111.222.333.444`

Now to check if it has been added type:

`pfctl -t blockedips -T show`

Update: Maybe this would help.

- Open the following file in vi:

  `vi /etc/pf.conf`
- Add the following line of code:

  `table <blockedips> persist file "/etc/pf.blocked.ip.conf"
   ext_if="bge0" # interface connected to internet`
- After that point, I would try restarting the firewall and confirming
  that the IP is blocked by typing:

  ```
  pfctl -d
  pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf
  pfctl -t blockedips -T show
  ```

Comment: I think the table needs to be set to block, but that part is not clear in the howto, I followed it, but the IP is still not blocked

Comment: Let me see if I can look up how to do so.

Comment: Just updated my answer, let me know if this helps

Comment: There is no need do disable and reenable pf to reload pf.conf. `pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf` is enough.

Comment: The `table` line is ok, but you need to add a `block` rule to make use of it. The `ext_if` macro only makes sense if by any chance you have an interface named `bge0` and if you use that macro later on the file.

Comment: (Bad) HOWTOs discourage thinking and encourage copying. Read `man pf.conf`, you'll be surprised at how good OpenBSD man pages are. Plus, `pf.conf` files need to be read as a whole (the order in which rules are put is crucial) so copying and pasting single lines is usually a bad idea. Create the file and the `table` rule (that much is correct) but either you share your whole `pf.conf` file or it's up to you to figure out the appropriate `block` rule and its location in the file.

Comment: Yea your preaching to the wrong choir, re-read my answer as i mentioned in the first place i am not too familiar with OpenBSD and that i provided a link that shows how to block IPs. If you think you got a solution comparable to my own, by all means submit it. But please stop critiquing my answer when i took time to research it.

Comment: @ryekayo Unless you can justify the inclusion of the `ext_if="bge0"` macro and why you don't have a block rule then I _will_ criticize your answer, because it is incomplete (i.e. not a proper answer), regardless of the effort you put into it. Plus my comment regarding HOWTOs was addressed at the OP, not you (apologies, I should have made that clear).