# How do I add more IP addresses to my pf rules?

Tags: vpn, openbsd, pf

I wish to have all internet traffic to go through my VPN; when my VPN is disconnected, all internet traffic can not go out of my workstation/desktop (not server).

I wish to switch VPN servers of one location to another at random.

Here's my pf rules. I would appreciate if you can help me add more IP addresses of remote VPN servers:

```
wan="em0"
vpn="tun0"
block all
block in log all
set block-policy drop
set skip on lo
antispoof for $wan inet
block in from urpf-failed to any
block inet proto icmp icmp-type echoreq
block out inet6 all
block in inet6 all
pass out on $wan proto tcp from any to a.b.c.d port 443 modulate state
pass out on $vpn proto tcp from any to any port 80 modulate state
pass out on $vpn proto tcp from any to any port 443 modulate state
pass out on $vpn proto udp from any to any port 53 modulate state
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the IP address of the remote VPN server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tables. See `man pf.conf` for a detailed explanation and take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154764/77520) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-T add` to add one or more addresses in a table and automatically create a non-existing table.
So you have to do a command like this.

```
sudo pfctl -t badguys -T add 185.130.5.160
```

If you don't have such a table already, it will be created.

```
1 table created. 1/1 addresses added.
```

Now if you look in `badguys`, you will see the new IP.

```
sudo pfctl -t badguys -T show
```

Now restart pf.

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
```